# Homescreen changes via iOS Enterprise Remote Device Management

Tags: ios, remote-control, mdm, configuration-profiles, enterprise

I'm trying to find out if it is possible on the iOS Developer Enterprise Program to remotely add a home screen bookmark to a website.

For example: a user can visit a website and add a shortcut to that webpage to their home screen in Mobile Safari via the Share context menu and picking "Add to Homescreen". I want to be able to reproduce this remotely to all the devices under my control as a matter of automation.

I understand that Apple have a Mobile Device Management Protocol (MDM) that can be used to install a configuration profile to devices. The documentation lists the following about configuration profiles:

> A configuration profile contains a number of settings that you can
>   specify, including:
>
> - Restrictions on device features
> - Wi-Fi settings
> - VPN settings
> - Email server settings
> - Exchange settings
> - LDAP directory service settings
> - CalDAV calendar service settings
> - Web clips Credentials and keys

So there's nothing there about home screen configuration.

Is there any way of remotely adding home screen bookmarks to iOS devices?

---

*PS. I'm aware that a work around to this is to create a browser wrapper application and remotely push this app. However, that is not what I wish to do.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bingo! you've already got it there in your question.

Your last item "Web clips Credentials and keys" should actually be two - "Web Clips" and "Credentials and Keys" in which case, "Web Clips" is the one you're looking for. A "Web Clip" is a home screen bookmark for a website.

From the Enterprise Deployment Guidelines:

> **Web Clip Settings**
>
> Use this payload to add web clips to the Home screen of the user’s device. Web clips
> provide fast access to favorite web pages.
> Make sure the URL you enter includes the prefix http:// or https://—this is required
> for the web clip to function correctly. For example, to add the online version of
> the iPhone User Guide to the Home screen, specify the web clip URL:
> http://help.apple.com/iphone/
> To add a custom icon, select a graphic file in gif, jpeg, or png format, 59 x 60 pixels in
> size. The image is automatically scaled and cropped to fit, and converted to png format
> if necessary.

Comment: Oh great! I didn't realise that's what "Web Clips" meant, more Apple-specific terminology to learn :)